# Print only one list in recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion, binary, compression

In the following code, I return the integer value for the amount of consecutive numbers in a given string.

```
def consecutive_length(S):
    if S == '':
        return 0
    if len(S) == 1:
        return 1
    if S[0] == S[1]:
        return 1 + consecutive_length(S[1:])
    return 1

def compress(S):
    if S == '':
        return 0
    cons_length = consecutive_length(S)
    return [cons_length] + [compress(S[cons_length:])]
```

When I run this print statement, the following is returned:

```
>>> print (compress('1111000000001111000111111111111111'))
[4, [8, [4, [3, [15, 0]]]]]
```

Where I really want the following to be returned:

```
>>> print (compress('1111000000001111000111111111111111'))
[4, 8, 4, 3, 15]
```

Comment: Take out the brackets in `[compress(S[cons_length:])]`

Comment: @zondo If I do that, I get an error saying `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`

Comment: Ah, yes.  Do it anyway, but in any case where you would return an integer, (such as `return 0`), change it to returning a list: `return [0]`

Comment: @zondo If you make that a formal answer, I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: I think you actually want to return `[]`

Comment: @gtlambert: Yes, thank you.  I put that in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return a list, `[what_is_returned]` will be a nested list, but when you return an integer, it will be just a list.  Instead, (in `compress()`) ,always return a list, and remove the brackets when you use what it returns:

```
def consecutive_length(S):
    if S == '':
        return 0
    if len(S) == 1:
        return 1
    if S[0] == S[1]:
        return 1 + consecutive_length(S[1:])
    return 1

def compress(S):
    if S == '':
        return []
    cons_length = consecutive_length(S)
    return [cons_length] + compress(S[cons_length:])
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to your method is to use `itertools.groupby()`:

```
from itertools import groupby

s = '1111000000001111000111111111111111'
answer = [len([digit for digit in group[1]]) for group in groupby(s)]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[4, 8, 4, 3, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
def consecutive_length(S):
    if S == '':
        return 0
    if len(S) == 1:
        return 1
    if S[0] == S[1]:
        return 1 + consecutive_length(S[1:])
    return 1

def compress(S):
    if S == '':
        return []
    cons_length = consecutive_length(S)
    return [cons_length] + compress(S[cons_length:])
```